# swap-файл. не понимаю как создать файл

Tags: linux

Создайте swap-файл размером 1Гб
Добавьте настройку чтобы swap-файл подключался автоматически при перезагрузке виртуальной машины (подсказка: необходимо внести изменения в файл /etc/fstab)
не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: Посмотрите https://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/how-do-i-add-swap-after-system-installation там всё описано

Answer (score 1):

```
fallocate -l 1G /swap
# или dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap bs=1M count=1k
mkswap /swap
chmod 600 /swap
echo "/swap  none    swap    sw    0   0" >> /etc/fstab
swapon /swap
```

Comment: хочу процитировать `man swapon`: https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/mount/swapon.8.en.html `The swap file implementation in the kernel expects to be able to write to the file directly, without the assistance of the filesystem. This is a problem on files with holes ... The most portable solution to create a swap file is to use dd(1) and /dev/zero.`, лучше не надо fallocate

Comment: А опция -d не для затыкания дыр в файле?

Comment: Или наоборот чтоб дыр наделать... Май энглишь ис вери бэд) закинул в английский вопрос коммент - надеюсь прилетят не только какашки , но и разъяснения))

Comment: mkswap мне кажется растянет пустой файл надежнее чем dd который в 100500 мануалах пишется по блоку в 4к и запросто может побиться между записями . ну к коллайдеру

Comment: результаты по колайдеру: и dd и fallocate делают фрагментированные файлы, но без дырок. `filefrag  swap-dd
swap-dd: 54 extents found` и `filefrag  swap-fallocate
swap-fallocate: 20 extents found`

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так

```
/var/cache/swap/myswap    none    swap    sw    0   0
```